# MySQLi On 3 Separate Queries At Once

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I'm trying to check whether or not an injectable parameter I found is actually exploitable in a bug bounty contest my college is holding. The code base is open source so I have access to the exact SQL queries being used.

The issue is this - the injectable parameter is used in 2 select queries before it is used in the vulnerable UPDATE query. All 3 queries are in different tables. Stacking queries is naturally turned off.

The injectable parameter is `$vulnParam`

The first select query must return exactly one row (there is a check in the php source for whether a single row is returned or not) and the query is,

```
select param2 from table1 where vulnParam='$vulnParam' and param2='$param2' and day='$day';
```

The second select query must return at least one row and the query is,

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE vulnParam='$vulnParam' AND param2='$param2' AND date='$sql_date';
```

And the third query is the one which is exploitable,

```
update table3 set vulnParam='$vulnParam',is_cancelled=0 where param3='$param3' and param2='$param2' and date='$day_date';
```

I cannot think of any way to check which command is being currently executed and then execute the payload only on the 3rd query. Is there some way to do this or is this bug completely safe?

(The injection is blind if that matters)